# What is the radius of a circle tangent to two lines with a known angle between them

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

Given angle, $\alpha$, and distance, $d$, what is the radius, $r$, and angle, $\theta$, in the image below in terms of the known quantities?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $\sin \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \dfrac{r}{r+d}$, and $\dfrac{\theta}{2} = 90^\circ - \dfrac{\alpha}{2}$.

Comment: Yup. Should have seen that. (P.S. if it's a load off your conscience, this isn't for homework)

Comment: Hmm, isn't it $\sin\frac12\alpha=r/(r+d)$?

Comment: Also $\frac12(\alpha+\theta)=\frac12\pi$

Comment: I can't blame ah-huh, it wasn't that clear in my illustration.

Comment: In your defense, it isn't clear where $\alpha$ is supposed to be. But I think the little arc is intended to indicate its span.

Comment: @NealKruis: Yes, I forgive. Just pointing out so the corrections can be made. I'm giving him +1 because it's a good solution. Also gave a tip of the hat on his responding comment.